# VS2013 Git -- Cannot complete the operation because of existing changes to the following file

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

Using VS 2013, I have made a change to a file, successfully committed and pushed to the server.  When I go to change to a different branch, I get the following error:

**Cannot switch to CM because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before you switch branches. See the Output window for details.**

The output window of course shows the file I just committed and pushed.  There are no files listed in the "Changes" area.

SourceTree shows no unstaged files and lets me change branches without a problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you attempted closing VS and reopening? I frequently get a similar issue and restarting it fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds weird, but last time I got this error message, all I had to do was physically remove the conflicted file and click on the "clear all" button of the output window. Until I cleared the error message, the bug continued.

In my case however I was doing a Pull, but the error message was the same (system claims to be pending commits but the change window is empty).

Comment: I did the same thing, physically removed the file, which let me switch branch once, but second time the issue is back again

Answer (score 1):

I tried the other two answers, no fix.

But here's what I tried that I believe made it reset itself in my case:

- Find the offending file in Explorer
- Rename it to remove its extension
- Go back to VS, you'll find the Changes window shows the file with the rename action
- Undo the rename change on that file

This should reset the state of the file and make it forget that there's a change on the file.
Now, you can simply switch or pull or do whatever was being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in my case i replaced a .jpg file with a new one with the same name but the new extension was ".JPG".

After changing the extension in the file shown in output window everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I came here in search of a solution to this same problem. Thanks to the hints given above, I discovered that the root project directory was missing a .gitignore file. After I copied one from another C# project into it, the problem went away. [My Gitignore is pretty conventional.](https://p6lists-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/p/dagray/Eby613xg1QlGtwrmNS7EnO8BUBGWIPREvVcAK8kSYw8y8w?e=U1i5mg)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. View History of current branch
2. Reset Hard to your last commit
3. Checkout the other branch

Answer (score 0):

Use these following commands :

```
$ git fetch --all
$ git reset --hard origin/master     
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master
```